# How to select an sub-element (se) of another element (e), but do not include one of sub-elements of selected sub-element (sse)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Example:

```
.element
  |
  |-.subelement
      |
      |-.subsubelement1
      |-.subsubelement2
      |-.subsubelement3
      |-.non-desired-subsubelement
      |-.subsubelement4
```

So how not to list all desired subsubelements (e.g. is unknown), but still receive an aggregated element `.subelement` of its subelements `.subsubelementX` without `.non-desired-subsubelement`:

**NOT an array**: `[subsubelement1, subsubelement2, subsubelement3, subsubelement4]`

**BUT an aggregate element**: `subelement`, without `non-desired-subsubelement` as its descendant:

```
  .subelement
    |
    |-.subsubelement1
    |-.subsubelement2
    |-.subsubelement3
    |-.subsubelement4
```

I thought about this:

```
$('.element .subelement:not([class^="non-desired-subsubelement"])') // selects subelements which has no class non-desired-subsubelement
```

would be nice to have something like:

```
$('.element .subelement:not(>>this<<:has([class^="non-desired-subelement"]))')
```

i.e. uses negative "has" selector; or something like:

```
$('.element .subelement:has-not([class^="non-desired-subelement"])') // much nicer
```

Or is it **easier** to get the `.subelement` and than remove the `.non-desired-subsubelement`, so to do it in two steps?

```
var subelement = $('.element .subelement');
subelement.remove('.non-desired-subsubelement');
```

May be there is still a complex selector?

Comment: what is your problem actually..?

Comment: to select an element without some of its descendants in an elegant way and not in multiple steps (as I proposed at the bottom of the question). Oder in other words: to select an element whose descendants has no non-desired classes

Comment: try this `$('.element .subelement').not(this).not(':has([class^="non-desired-subelement"])');`

Comment: @dreamweiver: it does't include subelements which have `non-desired-subsubelement` class. it doesn't exclude the subsubelements

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). There is no concept of an "aggregated element" - whatever that means - in selectors. You have a selector, you have a tree, and zero or more elements in that tree may match the selector. If you're using jQuery, then you have a collection of elements that match the selector, which happens to be exactly what you *don't* want. If you just want to delete the non-desired subsubelement, then select it, delete it using `.remove()` and you'll have your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$('.element .subelement [class^="sub"])`

Comment: nope, in this way I would only get an array of [".subsubelement1",".subsubelement2",".subsubelement3", ".subsubelement4"], not the ".subelement" with this array as an attribute. This is important to get an array of ".subelement" (if there were any: not in the initial example in the question), which has an array of only desired ".subsubelementX" as attributes. Still, thanks for a solution proposal.